# How to make input text as a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know how  to call it. when you put text in the textbox and hit the enter, the text you put in is packed as a box or something like circle.

something like this.

[image]

Can someone let me know what it's called and what language is used ?

thanks.

Comment: can u pls share ur code ? and also share that wat u have tried so far ?

Comment: I believe it's called tagging.  Google search and read, read, read.

Comment: What it's called is usually 'tagging,' and the language is most often [tag:JavaScript].

Comment: thanks it's called tagging !

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question; it's either a question asking "*what are these things called?*" *or* it's a question asking for help without clarifying what help is needed, and showing no code or effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use plugins for this. just like this one http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this example: 
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/tag-editor-field-using-jquery-similar-to-stackoverflow